# Opening Visual Studio Express 2012 projects in Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I was testing out Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop to get used to the new features(even though there aren't many), however my C# class uses VS 2010. I cannot seem to open a winform application that was created in VS 2012 in VS 2010.

Is there anyway I can allow the solution to open in 2010? I checked the microsoft documents on compatibility, however it wasn't very clear.

Comment: I think you're VS2010 instance needs to be at SP1, install that and see if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Visual Studio 2010 needs to have SP1 installed in order to go back and forth between 2012 and 2010.

Answer (score 0):

it only works between VS2010 sp1  and VS2012 
this link might help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx